# Removing ASCII artwork

Tags: php, ascii-art

I'm working on a plugin that allows a client to copy / past raw HTML from a source and publish but with certain elements removed / replaced.

I've tried variations of find / replace i.e. `$text = str_replace('', '', $text);` without luck.

I have it doing everything EXCEPT replacing the ascii artwork which looks as so:

```
                                         ``
                                       `;;;;`
                                      ;;;;;;;;
                                    ;;;;;;;;;;;;
                                  :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                                :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                              :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                            ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
                          ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
                        .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
                      .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
                    `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
                  `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
                 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
                 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
                  .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
                    ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
                      ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
                        :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                          :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                            :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                 .;;:         ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;         :;;.
               .;;;;;;,        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;         ,;;;;;;.
             `;;;;;;;;;;,        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        ,;;;;;;;;;;`
           `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.        `;;;;;;;;;;;;`        .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
          ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        .;;;;;;;;.        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
          ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        .;;;;.        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
           `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        ,,        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
             `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;                ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
               `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
                 .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:        :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
                   .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:    :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
                     ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;::;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
           ,;;         ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,         ;;,
         .;;;;;;         :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:         ;;;;;;.
       `;;;;;;;;;:         :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:         :;;;;;;;;;`
     `;;;;;;;;;;;;;:         :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:         :;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
   `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:         ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;         :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
  .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
   .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
     ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.        `;;;;;;;;;;`        .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
       ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        .;;;;;;.        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
         :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        .;;.        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
           :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`                `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
             :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;              ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
               ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;          ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
                 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:      :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
                  `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:  :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
                    `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
                      .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
                        .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
                          ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
                            ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
                              :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                                :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                                  :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                                    ;;;;;;;;;;;;
                                      ;;;;;;;;
                                       `;;;;`
                                         ``
```

**How can I remove ascii artwork in the head of an html doc?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why previous syntax didn't work... There are only two things that are different than attempts prior...

1. Slept on it.
2. Moved my keys to an include file.

Once these were in place I found success. I'm not sure that it's an answer exactly, but here's the exact output.

```
$ascii_artwork      =   '                ``
                                       `;;;;`
                                      ;;;;;;;;
                                    ;;;;;;;;;;;;
                                  :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                                :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                              :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                            ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
                          ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
                        .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
                      .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
                    `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
                  `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
                 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
                 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
                  .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
                    ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
                      ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
                        :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                          :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                            :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                 .;;:         ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;         :;;.
               .;;;;;;,        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;         ,;;;;;;.
             `;;;;;;;;;;,        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        ,;;;;;;;;;;`
           `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.        `;;;;;;;;;;;;`        .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
          ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        .;;;;;;;;.        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
          ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        .;;;;.        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
           `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        ,,        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
             `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;                ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
               `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;            ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
                 .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:        :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
                   .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:    :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
                     ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;::;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
           ,;;         ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,         ;;,
         .;;;;;;         :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:         ;;;;;;.
       `;;;;;;;;;:         :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:         :;;;;;;;;;`
     `;;;;;;;;;;;;;:         :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:         :;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
   `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:         ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;         :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
  .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
   .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
     ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.        `;;;;;;;;;;`        .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
       ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        .;;;;;;.        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
         :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`        .;;.        `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
           :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`                `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
             :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;              ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
               ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;          ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
                 ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:      :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
                  `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:  :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
                    `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`
                      .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
                        .;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;.
                          ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
                            ,;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;,
                              :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                                :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                                  :;;;;;;;;;;;;;;:
                                    ;;;;;;;;;;;;
                                      ;;;;;;;;
                                       `;;;;`
                                         ``';
$ascii_artwork      =>      'FOOBAR',
```

Comment: find the elements that contain, as `text` or `innerHTML`, the `ascii_artwork` and replace them with an empty one or delete the content. Share your code so we know what you are facing...

Comment: I wasn't sure about the white-spaces. I literally copied the entire value and tried pasting it once again and it finally worked. I think it was a matter of how I formatted the variable, but I couldn't tell you exactly how.